# Creating a custom UICollectionView class with an optional header delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I intend to use the same collection view style in multiple View Controllers throughout my app so I created a custom UICollectionView class. However, only some of the View Controllers will have a header for that collection view. Is it possible to create a delegate to allow for an optional `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` to be in each view controller without any of the other required protocols?

```
protocol FeedDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView
}

class FeedCollectionView: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
     //Custom UICollectionView
}
```

Intended Use

```
class VC1 {
   //Use FeedCollectionView without header
}

class VC2: FeedDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        //Access header protocol
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you making your collection view its own delegate and datasource?

Comment: Currently yes. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: I do believe so. That way you're not only sticking header configuration, but all data source and delegate methods to de collectionview itself (cells configuration, selection, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if you call `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` you must return a view. And to avoid problems view should be dequeued from collectionview (it needs to be registered first).

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String,
                        at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        return collectionView
            .dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader,
                                                               withReuseIdentifier: "",
                                                               for: indexPath)
}
```

So what you can do instead is adding a `Bool` to your collectionview. Something like `showHeader` that you can set from your VC, and change the header size according to it (setting (0, 0) when `showHeader == false`

However I would suggest, in case you want to keep your collectionview as its own delegate & dataSource (I don't know your use case but I don't think that is a good idea in most cases.), subclass it so you have

```
class FeedCollectionView: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
     // Does not configure any header
}

class HeaderFeedCollectionView: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
     // Implements that method
```

}